# How to use select2() for dynamic append table tr

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I have to use `select2()` for dynamic append `table tr`.

But it's not working. I have include the following plugins,

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

and following sample code,

```js
$(".select2_demo_1").select2();
```

```html
<select class="form-control select2_demo_1" id="list" name="empname[]"><option value="addcust">New Customer</option></select>
```

Comment: how do you append to your table?

Comment: Please complete the question, I cannot understand what you have to append and where. There is not code to analyze and there is not plugins list.

Comment: @selva, did you put `$(".select2_demo_1").select2();` in script tags or did you just throw it in the HTML like your code sample shows?

Comment: <select class="form-control select2_demo_1" id="list" name="empname[]"><option value="addcust">New Customer</option></select>